# Преобразовать массив объектов в другой вид

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Есть такой массив объектов:

```
[ 
    {
        "year" : "1959",
        "data" : {
            "Яблоки" : 2794966,
            "Грушы" : 3974229,
            "Арбузы" : 762131,
            ...
        }
    }, 
    {
        "year" : "1970",
        "data" : {
            "Яблоки" : 4238395,
            "Грушы" : 5521917,
            "Арбузы" : 933461,
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Как преобразовать его в такой вид:

```
{
    labels: ['1959', '1970', ...],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Яблоки',
            data: [2794966, 4238395, ...]
        },
        {
            label: 'Грушы',
            data: [3974229, 5521917, ...]
        },
        {
            label: 'Арбузы',
            data: [762131, 933461, ...]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Я говорю что тут помогают, а не решают за Вас. Просто "Дано" и решайте мне - это тут неприемлемо.

Comment: я не говорю решать, а прошу помочь.

Comment: Почитайте притчу и поймите разницу: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41289934#41289934

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собираете года в один массив, фрукты в другой, типа:

```
var years = [];
var fruits = {};
```

Заполняете данными, примерно так:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    years.push(data[i]['year']);

    for(var fruit in data[i]['data']) {
        if(fruits[fruit] == undefined) {
            fruits[fruit] = [];
        }

        fruits[fruit].push(data[i]['data'][fruit]);
    }
}
```

И потом стоите массив так, как вам нужно:

```
var data = {};
data['labels'] = years;
data['datasets'] = [];

for(var fruit in fruits) {
    data['datasets'].push({
        'label': fruit,
        'data': fruits[fruit]
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, работает!

Answer (score 6):

Просто берёте и меняете структуру. Например, так:

```js
const initial = [ 
    {
        "year" : "1959",
        "data" : {
            "Яблоки" : 2794966,
            "Грушы" : 3974229,
            "Арбузы" : 762131
        }
    }, 
    {
        "year" : "1970",
        "data" : {
            "Яблоки" : 4238395,
            "Грушы" : 5521917,
            "Арбузы" : 933461
        }
    }
];

const data = {
  labels: initial.map(item => item.year),
  datasets: []
};
for (let l in initial[0].data) {
  data.datasets.push({
    label: l, 
    data: initial.map(item => item.data[l])
  });
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам тоже, но через map вышла какой-то ошибка.

Comment: @БекжанСейткали "какая-то"? Не знаю такого типа ошибки, наверное очень редкий...

Comment: @БекжанСейткали вообще-то, нажав кнопку "Выполнить код" вы можете увидеть что код полностью рабочий